# A word that means "one is so rash about a political cause that even simple, unrelated things are misinterpreted"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a connotation here of being a bit overzealous, maybe even unreasonable.

Imagine the person who goes on a rant about environmental saftey when someone says "pass the butter".

Comment: One that fits this description might be referred to as a *zealot*, or a *partisan*. *Stubborn* is another word that comes to mind.

Comment: The term "touchy" comes to mind. That person is **too touchy** about environmentalism. "Sensitive" works in a similar way.

Comment: Bigot is the first thing that came to mind for me.

Comment: @SUMGUY *bigot* doesn't really apply here... there's no indication that the people that he is ranting at share a different opinion.

Comment: The word I'd use is *fanatic*: A person marked or motivated by an extreme, unreasoning enthusiasm, as for a cause.

Comment: Are you really looking for a single word that means all that you describe, including *political*? This is like asking for a single word for someone who is angry at his car mechanic because she is a Yankees fan and plays harmonica underwater every other Thursday from 6pm till 8pm. Alas, this seems to be the norm on EL&U these days.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite in this regard is *wingnut*:

> - slang :  one who advocates extreme measures or changes ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wing%20nut))
> - an American slang term for a person who holds extreme political (especially right-wing) views ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingnut))

Answer (score 0):

"Blindered" like horses. "Compulsive," "overfocused," "hyperfocused." I know these don't have the political overtones, but they capture the hypersensitivity and the inability to see anything else.